# Will 5/4 treated deck boards span 20”?

Tags: deck

I am building a houseboat and I am torn between using 5/4 deck boards or just using 2x6s for deck boards. My joists are on 20” centers. My main issue is I am wanting to save on weight because I only have so much buoyancy. The 5/4s boards will be significantly lighter than using the 2x6s. Anyone have any input on this ? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect having closer joists would give desired rigidity for cheaper in weight than 2x6s

Comment: Yea I am aware of that. The platform is already assembled at 20” center.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my house's deck built by a previous occupant, 5/4 did fine to span 24" joists.  It was a bit springy, but it was fine.  Though I'd check the mfgr specs on the specific 5/4 you're planning on using to confirm that 20" span is within spec.